# How was the double meaning/use of "prego" in the sequence "prego-grazie-prego" born?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, history

How come in Italian the same word is used to express the action of offering/inviting and afterwards to respond to the person who thanked you. What's the origin of it and how come the verb "to pray" is used for this?

Comment: As far as I can tell sequence you cited doesn't exist. In fact if you use 'prego' the other person responds 'grazie', and you cannot further adding anything, not even 'prego' again.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis That is not true. I heard it numerous times used as the English equivalent of "with welcome", French equivalent "avec plaisir" etc.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis he's referring to the two different meanings and usages of the word *prego*: the first is "here it is/here you are/please", the second is "you're welcome"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have any official reference for this, but from a logic perspective it means "la prego", it being a warm and polite invitation to accept an offer (a door held open, for instance).

In the same way, when someone says "Grazie", "Prego" is an invitation to stop thanking - again, polite - because the gratitude has been acknowledged.

Comment: @clabacchio, that is not true, the second prego is 'with welcome' 'you're welcome'

Comment: @rano I know ;) but when it comes to the ethimology, that's my answer